# regex jquery validations

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

There is a field for "experience" where users can submit the value with space but not more than two spaces between each word.

If they type then it should display an error message. Below are my code and its working in another way. It checks the user's input and if there are no more than two space then it's showing the error message. I don't want that.

I want to display the error message when a user enters more than two spaces between each word. Please try to solve this issue.

RegExp `/[ ]{2,}/`

```
e.validator.addMethod("descriptionType", function (e, i) {
    return e.match(/[ ]{2,}/)
}, "Please remove unwanted space");

$("#experiencemodalform").validate({
    rules: {
        experience: {
            descriptionType: !0
            , required: !0
            , minlength: 50
            , maxlength: 1500
        }
    }
    , messages: {}
    , submitHandler: function () {
        return !1
    }
    , ignore: ".ignore"
    , errorElement: "label"
    , errorClass: "has-error"
    , submitHandler: function (e) {
        e.submit()
    }
    , highlight: function (e) {
        $(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("success").addClass("has-error")
    }
});
```

Comment: `required` gets a Boolean `true` or `false`.  `!0` looks like a more verbose way to say `1`.   And then `return !1` inside the `submitHandler` instead of `0` or `false`.  Why are you programming like this?

Comment: @Sparky I was using true and false only. Before hosting the application I used some online js compress tool. Then it converted the code like `!0` `!1`.
Client requirement is users don't want to submit the value less than min character. Few people have used spaces and submit the value which is less than minimum character.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
return e.match(/^((?![ ]{2,}).)*$/gm)
```

Comment: But it didn't work after user click enters inside the textarea. Its working fine for the input field.

Comment: @user7152572, you've shown us absolutely no HTML in your question, so this answerer could not possibly know why your `textarea` is not working.  My guess is that's because you've only applied the rule to one field; and that's only based on the code you've posted in the OP.  If you want a good answer, you'll need to post a good question.

Comment: @Sparky please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/1485/ client requirement is if there is any space in the textarea it should display the error message. Its working fine for one line. If a user clicks the enter then the validation is not working. Please help